# Why declaring TextViews gloabally doesn't fetch data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public void loadUserInformation() {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference usesrRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(Uid);
    final ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ImageView profilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = postSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                String status = postSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

                Name.setText(name);
                Status.setText(status);

                Name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(image).into(profilePic);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Loading UserDetails", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    usesrRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Its returning a null pointer exception on the line... String name = postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())

I know that if i declare and initialise the textviews inside the onDatachange it will work... but i want the textviews to be invisible before this method is called... and when this method is called i want it to be visible... how can i achieve this?

Comment: post a code with Textview declaration and with error log

Comment: ONCREATE ......

Comment: Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        addData = (SubmitButton) findViewById(R.id.save);

        Name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Error...............

Comment: http://ibb.co/gmzWXS

Comment: You can update your question and add these details there

Comment: Never mind i figured out what the problem was

Comment: Good, in that case you should Answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Post the error you are getting,

Make your textview final,

and remember to stick to convention when naming  variable(Your textview should start with small letter).